# Accessing raw file permissions(Linux)

Tags: linux, file-permissions

As far as I am aware(correct me if I'm wrong), Linux is storing the information about each file's owner and permissions in a couple of bytes at the beginning of the file.

I know that there are plenty of ways to get that information about a file(both using shell commands and the GUI), but what I'm really wondering is if there is a way to access(view) those permissions in their raw form.

Maybe a more correct way to ask this question is whether there is a way to view the complete file contents(I've seen the binary output of a file using `hexdump -C test.txt`, but it still doesn't contain those) including the owner/permissions data.

I guess that this information is only accessed in it's raw form in deep-core code, but I'm really curious if it's possible to access it in a different way.

Comment: You are mistaken. The owner and permissions are part of the filesystem metadata, not of the file's content.

Comment: I second what @EldritchConundrum explained. You might be interested in diving depper into the onternals of your file system though (as opposed to the internals of files). What commands you required depends on the file system. That way you can access many technical details, but be aware that you can also corrupt your file system.

Comment: I'm not sure where I got the idea that this information is stored in the file itself - I guess I've misread something online :)
Thanks for the tips, someday when I have extra time I might dig in deeper into file systems and how they work :)
One of the reasons I asked was because once I made the mistake to `chown -R myuser:mygroup /` which trashed everything and I had to do reinstall. I still could access my files(from a Live CD), but couldn't effectively change the permissions of the files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*>>As far as I am aware(correct me if I'm wrong), Linux is storing the information about each file's owner and permissions in a couple of bytes at the beginning of the file.*

**NO!**

This information is NOT stored in the file.  It is a part of the filesystem's storage.  Different file systems will store the binary data in different places.  Some file systems will store in the information in the directory file.  You should read more about filesystem permissions [here, on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions)

If you want to read permissions, since they are usually accessed from directory listings, look into the [ls command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ls).

If you *really* want to look at the "binary" data in it's "raw" form, look into opening and reading directory files in a programming language like C.